# Find duplicate entries of a column based off of 2 email addresses

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a MySQL database and running sql in phpmyadmin.

I'm trying to find duplicate entries for column venID. Duplicate venIDs ONLY for 2 email addresses -  e1@myemail.com AND e2@myemail.com.

This is what I have so far BUT I need to add the email addresses I want to compare.  Not sure how to do that.  Not sure if what I have is even a good start.  Can someone help?

```
SELECT venID, email, count(*) as dupCount  
FROM thetable, thetable2 
WHERE venID and email 
GROUP BY venID, email HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT venID, email, count(*) as dupCount  
FROM thetable, thetable2 
WHERE email in ('e1@myemail.com','e2@myemail.com') 
GROUP BY venID, email 
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

If you also want to select only a specific venID, you can use this:

```
SELECT venID, email, count(*) as dupCount  
FROM thetable, thetable2 
WHERE email in ('e1@myemail.com','e2@myemail.com') 
    AND venID = 2
GROUP BY venID, email 
HAVING count(*) > 1
```